# How to find and move an .exe from one folder to another

Tags: linux, find, mv

The operating system is Lubuntu. I managed to move `.txt` , `.c` and `.h` files, but with my method I cannot move `.exe` files. I used this command for `.c`, etc:

```
find /home/csuser/testfiles . -type f -name "*.c" -exec mv '{}' /home/csuser/src/ \;
```

Comment: What happens when you run the command for the .exe files?

Comment: nothing at all. i changed the command to:.... -type f -executable-exec mv '{}' .... and it seems to work. however it moves some more .exe but i thing i got it covered